# Pass props to v-dialog from parent to child in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vue and have looked at some answers regarding my problem in which, I want to pass an id (for example `0099`) from my child component to the parent via v-model. Is this possible, to pass an ID this way?

Here's my child code:

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="show" width="unset">
    <v-card class="px-15 py-8" elevation="0">
      <div class="px-6 py-8 mb-n4 text-center">
        <span class="lucky-point--text text-h6">
          Are you sure you want to access this employee?
        </span>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

What I want is that in `v-model="show"` I want to also include some id of an employee. Example `v-model="show[0099]` to the parent.

my parent code:

```html
<ClaimDialog
 :id="item.employeeid"
 />
```

although I used some props.

```js
props: {
 id: Number
}
```

Once I click from parent dialog it gets stacked on top of one another. I have found one answer but on my side its a bit tricky, since I'm new to Vue, and this approach is different from mine, since mine has a child component. Here's that question: [Why are my dialogs stacked on top of one another? (Vuetify)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831688/why-are-my-dialogs-stacked-on-top-of-one-another-vuetify)

Answer (score 0):

### If you need to pass data from a child to a parent, then you must use $emit

- [Here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201/2) is an example of a question and answer
- [Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html?#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events) is a link to the official documentation

If these links do not help you, then update the question: what event should the data be transmitted on, and how your components are connected (more code from your components)